# Pagination CodeIgniter: Page, wrong link

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine, pagination

I'm using codeigniter's pagination class:

Have this in the controller:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/index.php/municipio/';
$config['total_rows'] = count($this->data['municipios']); 
$config['per_page'] = 2; 
$config['uri_segment'] = 2;
$config['first_link'] = false ;
$config['last_link'] = false ;
$config['prev_link'] = false;
$config['next_link'] = false;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

This is how I call the model function to obtain de DB rows:

```
$this->data['municipios'] =  $this->Municipio_model->obtenerMunicipiosPaginacion($pagina,$config['per_page']);
```

This is what I have in the model:

```
function obtenerMunicipiosPaginacion( $pagina , $registros_por_pagina )
{

    $limite_inferior = ($pagina * $registros_por_pagina) - $registros_por_pagina;
    $limite_superior = $registros_por_pagina;
    $query = 'SELECT m FROM Entities\Municipio m ORDER BY m.nombre ASC';
    $create_query = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery($query)->setFirstResult($limite_inferior)->setMaxResults($limite_superior);
    $variable = $create_query->getResult();
    return $variable;
}
```

In the view, the class is printing links like this, which is okey, but:

1 2 3

1 link works perfectly, it takes me to the page municipios/1

2 link works perfectly, it takes me to the page municipios/2

3 link takes me to the page municipios/6

I'm sure the problem is not with the DB query, must be some configuration on pagination class.

I have seen this question a lot, but didn't see an answer that solved my problem.

***EDIT:***

**It seems to work now, I added this line:**

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: [link]http://godbit.com/article/pagination-with-code-igniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

It seems to work now, I added this line:

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```